# Supply basic http authentication

Tags: jsf

I have a scenario where I have button which need to open up a new tab and go to an external site. This site require sbasic HTTP authentication. So I need to supply the credntials but am unsure how.

Usually I would do something like this inside of my method (which a command button would invoke) to redirect to a new page:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.redirect("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Which of course works, but I can't find if using ExternalContext I can then send Basic Authentication credentials in the header?

Comment: Did you try `http://username:password@stackoverflow.com` ?

Comment: IE and Chrome don't support this anymore.

Comment: So you are effectively asking is how to do something that you already know is not possible...

Comment: No.Just because one way of doing is no longer supported doesn't mean there is not a workaround(s) or a alternative way(s) to implement something.I am looking for alternatives as I am sure there must be a way to modify the headers.